# Stripe table JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to make a table which will display colours for odd and even table rows, not sure where I'm going wrong

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tableStyles" border="1">
  <th>Heading 1</th>
  <th>Heading 2</th>
  <th>Heading 3</th>
  <tr>
    <td>Odd</td>
    <td>Odd</td>
    <td>Odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Even</td>
    <td>Even</td>
    <td>Even</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Odd</td>
    <td>Odd</td>
    <td>Odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Odd</td>
    <td>Odd</td>
    <td>Odd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
var isEven = function(someNumber) {
  return (someNumber%2 == 0) ? true : false;
};
if isEven = true {
  var styletab = document.getElementsByTagName("tableStyles");
  var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
  for (var i = 0; i < styletab.length; i++) {
    styletab[i].style.fontSize = "12px";
    styletab[i].style.color = "blue";
  }

} else {
  var styletab = document.getElementsByTagName("tableStyles");
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i = 0; i < styletab.length; i++) {
  styletab[i].style.fontSize = "12px";
  styletab[i].style.color = "red";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use css?

Comment: Check this. http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: It's to be done in JavaScript

Comment: Then look at your if statement, did you even try to debug this?

Comment: you know nothing jon snow.

Comment: I did it's saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Comment: `return (someNumber%2 == 0) ? true : false;` is redundant. You can just do `return someNumber %2 == 0`

Comment: a lot of issues with your code: isEven() is a function but you use it as a variable, the comparison is done by = instead of ==, a lot of duplication in if branch and else branch, can be moved outside of the if-else

Comment: Based on the comment to your (moderator-deleted) answer, it seems you want to know how to mark the question as "solved." All you have to do is click the check mark beside the answer you feel is correct and which most helped you. It's not obligatory, if your question isn't solved, but it's always appreciated. You can only check one answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code I can see that you are new to JS. So I think it is good to point out where you are going wrong, than fixing the whole thing for you.

```
//Here you are creating a function to return true or false using a function which
//already returning true or false.
var isEven = function(someNumber) {
  return (someNumber%2 == 0) ? true : false;
};
//above can be reduced to this.
(someNumber%2==0); //will return true if even and false if odd.

// The syntax of if statement is wrong. It should be if (statement) { do stuff here...}
// Notice the difference between '=' and '=='. The first assigns value and the second checks if both sides are same.
// The isEven function should have an input to give either true or false.
// Finally you should first get the rows in the table as an array and loop through it and then do this if statement.
if isEven = true {
  var styletab = document.getElementsByTagName("tableStyles");
  var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
  for (var i = 0; i < styletab.length; i++) {
    styletab[i].style.fontSize = "12px";
    styletab[i].style.color = "blue";
  }

} else {
  var styletab = document.getElementsByTagName("tableStyles");
var cells = table.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
for (var i = 0; i < styletab.length; i++) {
  styletab[i].style.fontSize = "12px";
  styletab[i].style.color = "red";
  }
}

// the above should be organised in the format below.
var table = ;//get the table here.
var rows = ;//get the rows in the table here.
for (i in rows) {
    var row = rows[i]; //get the current row
    var cells = ;//get cells from the current row
    if(i%2==0) {   
        //set formatting for the cells here if the row number is even.
    } else {
        //set formatting for the cells here if the row number is odd.
    }
}
```

Make sure you are absolutely sure of how the selectors (getElementById etc) work and what do they return so that you can use them correctly. for example getElementsByTagName searches based on the tag name ('div' 'table' etc) but getElementById searches by the id of the tags - 'tableStyles' in this case. Hope I pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: window.onload = function isEven()
  {
   someNumber%2==0;
  } 
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("tableStyles");//get the table here.
var rows = document.getElementById("tr");//get the rows in the table here.
for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
    var row = rows[i].getElementById("tr"); //get the current row
    var cells =  ;//get cells from the current row
    if(i%2==0) {   
  row[i].style.fontSize = "12px";
  row[i].style.color = "blue";
    } else {
        row[i].style.fontSize = "12px";
  row[i].style.color = "red";
    }
}

I have to admit the last part has me lost, any closer?

Comment: you are moving in the right direction but still have a lot of errors in your code. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ar5suz2g/3/ for solved final output. I have commented the code as much as I can. As mentioned before, this is not the best way to do what you are trying to do but it'll show the mistakes you are making in your approach. All the best learning JS.

Comment: Thank you, I think I need to look at some of the basics again

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#tableStyles tr'), function (tr) {
    tr.classList.add((tr.rowIndex%2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'));
});
```

This presumes you have styles set, in CSS, for `tr.odd` and `tr.even`; also that you're using a relatively up-to-date browser; Internet Explorer 8+ for `document.querySelectorAll()`, and Internet Explorer 9+ for `Array.prototype.forEach()`.

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#tableStyles tr'), function(tr) {
  // rowIndex is the index of the current <tr> in the table element:
  tr.classList.add((tr.rowIndex % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'));
});
```

```css
.even {
  color: red;
}
.odd {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableStyles" border="1">
  <th>Heading 1</th>
  <th>Heading 2</th>
  <th>Heading 3</th>
  <tr>
    <td>Odd</td>
    <td>Odd</td>
    <td>Odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Even</td>
    <td>Even</td>
    <td>Even</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Odd</td>
    <td>Odd</td>
    <td>Odd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Odd</td>
    <td>Odd</td>
    <td>Odd</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to stripe only those elements selected (without reference to the `rowIndex`):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#tableStyles tbody tr'), function(tr, collectionIndex) {
  // collectionIndex (regardless of name, it's the second argument) is
  // the index of the current array-element in the array/collection:
  tr.classList.add((collectionIndex % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'));
});
```

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#tableStyles tbody tr'), function(tr, collectionIndex) {
  tr.classList.add((collectionIndex % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'));
});
```

```css
.even {
  color: red;
}
.odd {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableStyles" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Heading 1</th>
      <th>Heading 2</th>
      <th>Heading 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Odd</td>
      <td>Odd</td>
      <td>Odd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Even</td>
      <td>Even</td>
      <td>Even</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Odd</td>
      <td>Odd</td>
      <td>Odd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Odd</td>
      <td>Odd</td>
      <td>Odd</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `[]` creates an empty array so calling the method from `Array.prototype` is better. +1

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realised; so literally `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of `[].forEach`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, thank you for the snippet (I'm on iPad, it's somewhat difficult to add snippets and long code on this thing) :)

Answer (score 0):

Final Correct answer provided by Balamurugan Soundarara

```
//Here we are searching for the document for element with the id 'tableStyles'. This returns only one DOM element.
var table = document.getElementById("tableStyles");

//Here we are searching the table element for all elements of the tag 'tbody'. This returns an array of elements. Here there is only one so we just use the first one (hence the [0] at the end)
var body = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

//Here we are searching the body element for all elements of the tag 'tr'. This returns an array of row elements.
var rows = body.getElementsByTagName("tr");

//Here we are looping through the elements in the rows array.
for (var i=0 ; i<rows.length; i++) {
    //Here we select the nth row in the array based on the loop index.
    var row = rows[i];

    //Here we are searching the row element for all elements of the tag 'td'. This returns an array of cells in the row.
    var cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td");

    //We are looping through all the cells in the array.
    for(var j=0; j<cells.length; j++) {
        //set the fontsize
        cells[j].style.fontSize = "12px";

        //check if the row is even. see how we dont need the isEven function. you can directly use the == function with the modulo operator.
        if( i%2==0 ) {
            //if it is even then the color is set to blue
            cells[j].style.color = "blue";
        } else {
            //if it is even then the color is set to blue
            cells[j].style.color = "red";
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ar5suz2g/4/